# How do I get off the island?

Tags: the-cave

I have **The Twins**, **The Adventurer**, and **The Monk**. I have gotten the boat to the other side of the island, but The Hermit has gotten himself a place on the boat.

I've got the Parrot to Sparky, but I can't find the Femur to make him bark (it's not where the Explosive Barrels were). Did I miss something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's possible you picked the femur up and moved it accidentally. Try scouring the island to see if that's the case.

In the event that is *not* the issue, you've encountered a bug. Quitting and reloading your save should reset the femur and you should be able to find it by the explosive barrels again.

Comment: Yep, I quit and reloaded the game. It was where it should have been. Thanks!